# Different data in each fragment in Android Studio's default tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I've created a project using the default tabbed activity and have 4 tabs. The fragment contains just one text box, and I want to change its contents depending on the current tab.

Here's what my **onCreateView** method looks like:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                textView.setText("The first");
            case 2:
                textView.setText("The second");
            case 3:
                textView.setText("The third");
            case 4:
                textView.setText("The fourth");
        }


        return rootView;
    }
```

The issue here is that the text box in all tabs shows *The fourth* regardless of which tab I'm currently on.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this all wrong. There are many tutorials on web you can go through. Following is the good example that explained well. Let me know if you require any further assistance after going through link.

[Android Tablayout Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)